# imagemagick from php issue

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm issuing the following command

```
convert /path/to/image.jpg +repage "/path/output.jpg"
```

it works perfectly fine from the command line, but i'm running it from php and its just not working, no output whatsoever.

Comment: i should also point out that the command is in a shell script (which is working from command line), has 777 permissions and the same user as the domain user

Comment: What do you mean running it from PHP? Are you doing a shell exec? Or running the equivalent commands via the native ImageMagick extension?

Comment: "it's just not working" is not very helpful... How are you running it?  What is the exit code of convert?  Of your shell?  Is it really the case that nothing at all is printed to stderr or stdout?  What about your error log?

Comment: yes sorry i'm using the php system() function

Comment: how do i find the exit code of convert?

Comment: when i said no output i meant from php system() function, which is supposed to display the output

Comment: what user/group should i set in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user running the web server process (which is almost certainly *not* the user that owns the script) needs to have write permissions to the destination path.

Alternatively, check out this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

You can do the processing right in PHP and avoid the ugly system() call completely.

Comment: yeah i have the imagick extension installed, unfortunately this is a hideously complicated shell script which i can't do via the extension

Answer (score 0):

**Check security execution settings** in your `PHP.ini` file, you must have disabled `safe_mode`, then this code was will working good.

```
echo exec("/path/to/convert /path/to/image.jpg +repage \"/path/output.jpg\"");
```